# How to make a video gallery

Tags: android, android-layout

I currently have a app that takes a video and stores them on the sdcard. What I want to do now is have another intent organize these videos in different gallery. I also would want to have it where the user could create new gallery and ad any video to any folder.

How would I do this. I have an idea but i'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to query mediastore for videos and thumbnails and other video related information. Then you can use a listview or grid view to display the contents.

Have a look at here. http://www.androidcookbook.info/android-media/full-mediastore-video-example.html

Comment: The app i'm trying to make is only going to display videos that are a certain length (like 5 or 10 seconds). Is there a way to filter this so i only get those videos rather than all the videos in my storage?